# Why does my bot mention the user on their account, but shows the users ID for other people viewing the ping while using embeds?

Tags: discord, discord.py, replit

Here is the welcome message code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  print(f"{member} has just joined")
  channel = bot.get_channel(ID)
  role = ID
  embed = EmbedBuilder (
    title = f"Welcome {member.mention} to the server!",
    description = "",
    color = 0xf1c40f
  ).build()
  await channel.send(embed=embed)
  role = get(member.guild.roles, id=role)
  await member.add_roles(role)
```

This will return the result:

```
Welcome <@MyUserId> to the server!
```

for other people, such as my alt account, but will successfully return

```
Welcome @Mentioned to the server!
```

for the persons own account to see. I have no idea why it only displays and pings successfully for the member who has joined, but wont display correctly for other people. Any help?

Comment: Mostly, the user is not in the cache of the other members, and therefore it will not show the mention correctly for them. I would also advise you to not mention a new user in the title, I am not sure if this will even work properly.

Comment: That's not really the issue @Dominik, it's a long-known fault on discord, only happens on mobile, there's sadly nothing you can do about it

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Did not know about that, sounded like a cache problem to me. Thanks for clarifying! :)

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński i thought that at first, but this seemed to only happen when i used it within an embed, because the original message worked perfectly without it, but i wanted to use an embed. But thanks for clearing this up for me